# how to inject view into the presenter using Dagger2 for android?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dependencies, dagger

I want to `inject` the `view (Activity object)` into the `Presenter`. Right now I am manually setting the view using a setter of the Presenter class. How do I achieve this using Dagger ? Can you please show me a sample code as to how to do it ?

**This is how the main Activity creates the Presenter as of now**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CountPresenter.View, ToastPresenter.View {

    @Inject
    CountPresenter countPresenter;
    @Inject
    ToastPresenter toastPresenter;
    TextView countText;
    Toast toast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        countText = findViewById(R.id.text_count);

        DaggerToastPresenterComponent.create().inject(this);
        DaggerCountPresenterComponent.create().inject(this);
        countPresenter.setView(this);
        toastPresenter.setView(this) ;

        findViewById(R.id.button_count).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countPresenter.incrementCount();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button_toast).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toastPresenter.handleToastButtonClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Presenter class code : **

```
public class CountPresenter {
    private Counter counter ;


    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    private View view ;

    @Inject
    public CountPresenter() {
        counter =  Counter.getInstance() ;
    }

    public void incrementCount(){
        counter.setCount(counter.getCount()+1);
        view.setCounterText(counter.toString());
    }

    public interface View {
        void setCounterText(String val) ;
    }
}
```

**Full Code here :**

https://github.com/nateshmbhat/FresherAssignment2020/tree/nateshmbhat/Apps/CounterApp_MVP_Dagger/app/src/main/java/com/techy/nateshmbhat/contacto

Comment: Post your presenter module !

Comment: I have provided the link to my project..

Answer (score 1):

I am going to write down steps

First, you need to add a **module** class

```
@Module
class CountPresenterModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providCountPresenter(): CountPresenter.View {
        return CountPresenter()
    }
}
```

Similarly add the module class for ToastPresenter

After, that add the reference of newly added module class in the AppComponent class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, .....,ToastPresenterModule::class, CountPresenterModule::class]){
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

And get amused by the magic of dagger/injection.

Part 2 in Java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ToastPresenterModule.class, CountPresenterModule.class}) {
   void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

Comment: can u please provide java code for "adding reference of newly added module" part of the code ...

Answer (score 0):

Helo,
here is my solution in Kotlin. First
you will create an interface

interface Contract{

```
    interface Presenter{
    fun setView(view: View)
}
```

}

then inside presenter, you will implement it (among other methods, which your presenter should have (after you predefined them in that interface))

```
: Contract.Presenter
```

inside presenter, you will create late init var view of type View

```
 private lateinit var view: View
```

then inside of presenter in the implementation of presenter interface, you will define this

```
override fun setView(view: View) {
    this.view = view
}
```

in MainActivity you will have

@Inject
lateinit var presenter: Contract.Presenter

and in on resume, you will set this as view

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    presenter.setView(this)
}
```

that is all,

Happy coding